# accidentally discarded unstaged change

Tags: git, github

I was using git gui to update my remote with my local, and there were a list of changes. I selected some of those files, staged them and commit them. I was planning to stage the rest of the changed file afterward, so that I can add two different commit comments. But now even after I click `rescan`, I cant see the files that I still haven't commit yet.

How should I approach this?

Comment: If your change is unstaged, git doesn't know about it. It's gone, unless your editor still has the data.

Comment: "still has the data" as in the data **before** the I changed them? I dont have the old files, is there a way to maybe compare my local with remote and then stage whatever is different?

Comment: if you have changed files stored somewhere in your computer (code editor backups and intermediate files with data for undo, whatever), then it's possible to recover at least something. Also consult `git reflog`, maybe you have made some commits abandoned later.